# Spring and AMQP RabbitMQ topic exchange not working

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to set up topic exchange on my spring app.
Here's my context configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    public class IntegrationConfig {

        public final static String queueName = "my-queue";

        @Bean
        AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);

        }

        @Bean
        Queue queue() {
            return new Queue(queueName);
        }

        @Bean
        TopicExchange exchange() {
            return new TopicExchange("my-exchange", false, true);
        }

        @Bean
        Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("ru.interosite.*");
        }

        @Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(queueName);
            container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
            return container;
        }

        @Bean
        ImageUploadReceiver receiver() {
            return new ImageUploadReceiver();
        }

        @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(ImageUploadReceiver receiver) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
        }

    }
```

This is receiver class:

```
    public class ImageUploadReceiver {
        private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public void receiveMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("Received ");
            latch.countDown();
        }

        public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return latch;
        }
    }
```

This is sender code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/sendmessage")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sendMessage() {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("ru.interosite.1", "ttt1233");
        try {
            imageUploadReceiver.getLatch().await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Msg received";
    }
```

So I'm sending message to topic exchange using binding key "ru.interosite.1" to the queue that was bound with pattern "ru.interosite.*". I used these key and pattern when tried sample from https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html and they worked fine.

But inside String AMQP it does not work, i.e. receiver never gets called. It called only if binding key and pattern are completely the same as if I were using DirectExchange.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the config for the `RabbitTemplate`, but I guess it is with default options.

To send a message to the `my-exchange` you must specify it directly:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my-exchange", "ru.interosite.1", "ttt1233");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sure I should've  guessed that template do not know exchange name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the exchange in the rabbit template like this:

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    // ... as above

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setExchange("my-exchange");
        return template;
    }

}
```

So you can send the message with:

```
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/sendmessage")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sendMessage() {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("ru.interosite.1", "ttt1233");
        // ... as above
    }

}
```